# Lower bounding weighted sample variance

Tags: variance, random-variable, sample, weights, weighted-mean

Let us assume that we draw a sample $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^N$ from a  random variable $X$ and we have a discrete probability distribution $q_{ij}$, i.e. $0 \leq q_{ij}\leq 1$ and $\sum_{ij} q_{ij} =1$ (the $q_{ij}$ are unralated with the random variable $X$).

I want to study the following figure of merit, more specifically I would like to lower bound this
$$
\sigma_X^q = \sum_{ij} q_{ij} (G_{ij} - \mu_{G})^2 = \sum_{i\neq j} q_{ij} (X_i-X_j)^2
$$
where $G_{ij} = X_{i}-X_{j}$ is the gap and $\mu_{G}=0$ since $G_{ij}=-G_{ji}$.

Now, this quantity can be lower bounded by considering that $q_{ij} \geq \min_{ij} q_{ij} = q_{\text{min}}$, obtaining

$$
\sigma^q_X \geq q_{\text{min}} \sum_{ij} (X_i -X_j)^2 = q_{\text{min}}2N(N-1) S^2
$$

where I have used the alternative expression for the sample variance

$$
S^{2}=\frac{1}{2N(N-1)} \sum_{ij} (X_{i}-X_{j})^{2}
$$

> My question is: can we lower bound this in smarter way? It seems to me that the problem is connected with the concept of weighted sample variance (see [Wikipedia article here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_arithmetic_mean#Weighted_sample_variance)) , but since the $q_{ij}$ are given in terms of two label, it is not clear to me if this is really connected with the weighted sample variance or how to translate this in the language of weighted sample variance (maybe grouping the pair of index $ij$ into one index $\alpha$, maybe considering the random variable of the difference of $X$ with $X$ (does it make any sense?)). Further, the weight are applied to the $G$ rather than to the actual random variable $X$.